# snappy ubuntu's ssh password not recognized

Tags: networking, boot, ssh

I am installing `raspberry` for the fist time. I have added [`snappy`](http://people.canonical.com/~platform/snappy/raspberrypi2/) and added it via my `OSX` using `dd` like commands. Now, I put some ethernet cable and try to `ssh`in the `raspberry` with `ssh ubuntu@someip` and with `ubuntu` as a password. But the password (and/or the user name) 
are not recognized. Did I do something wrong ?

Edit : `ssh ubuntu@169.254.95.147` and the output is `Permission denied (publickey,keyboard-interactive).`

Comment: There can't be much wrong if you are getting a prompt.  Could you cut&paste the actual dialog and add it to your question?

Answer (score 1):

A problem that I've encountered multiple times is that I will set the password locally before changing the keyboard layout (which, for me, is English US).  The default layout is UK, so when I enter my password it records the characters appropriate to the UK layout.  When I then try to ssh into the rpi, the characters that are sent are from the US layout, and so don't match.

Make sure to change the keyboard layout before setting your password.